# Array-based stack

Tags: java, stack

Description:

> An array-based `Stack` class. Since this class is designed using an array the size of the `Stack` is limited to whatever the program gives you. The key reason was not to use any outside help like `Arrays.copyOf(array, size)` to increase size etc. (In future, `LinkedStack` will solve size problem). `MAX_SIZE` is made public to let a user know about `MAX_SIZE` and `size()` returns current size of the `Stack`. Return value `int` is used to make sure all push/insertions are successful on `Stack`.

Right now I'm just looking for suggestions to improve my code before I push it to my GitHub account.

```
package Stack;

public class StackArray
{
   public static final int MAX_SIZE = 1040;   // MAX size of a Stack
   private int topLook;                       // current element on Stack
   private int stackElements[];               // array to store Stack elements

public StackArray()                        // default constructor creates a Stack with capacity of 50
{
    topLook = -1;                          // initially no elements on the Stack
    stackElements = new int[MAX_SIZE];    // an array of MAX_SIZE gets created
}

public int size()                          // returns current size of the Stack
{
    return (topLook + 1);
}

public boolean emptyCheck()                // returns true if this Stack has no elements in it, false otherwise
{
    return (topLook == -1);
}

public boolean fullCheck()                 // returns true if this Stack is full, false otherwise
{
    return (topLook == MAX_SIZE - 1);
}

public int top()                           // returns top element of the Stack, -1 otherwise
{
    if (!emptyCheck())
    {
        return stackElements[topLook];
    }
    return -1;
}

public int push(int value)                 // push passed argument on the Stack. 1 indicates insertion was successful, -1 otherwise
{
    if (!fullCheck())
    {
        stackElements[++topLook] = value;
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

public int pop()                           // returns top element of the Stack and remove it, -1 otherwise
{
    if (!emptyCheck())
    {
        return stackElements[topLook--];
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: You package name does not comply with the java naming standards (should all be lowercase); and your indentation is also non standard. (See the double curly braces at the end)

Answer (score 14):

The methods named `emptyCheck()` and `fullCheck()` are ambiguous. They should be named `isEmpty()` and `isFull()` respectively.

Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

## Formatting

You should clean up your indention. The methods should be indented to the same level as the fields and it is common in Java to place the opening bracket on the same line as the matching statement. For example:

```
public class StackArray {

   public static final int MAX_SIZE = 1040;
   private int topLook;
   private int stackElements[];

   // Note the indentation and position of the bracket here.
   public StackArray() {
      topLook = -1;                          
      stackElements = new int[MAX_SIZE];
   }

   // ...

}
```

## Comments

Comments such as

```
public static final int MAX_SIZE = 1040;   // MAX size of a Stack
```

that just repeat what the line does are pointless.

Also you can minimize the number of comments by choosing better variable/method names. Take for example:

```
private int topLook;                       // current element on Stack
```

If you call the variable `currentElement` (or `topElement`), the comment becomes unnecessary.

Some of your comments are simply wrong (or you didn't update them) such as:

```
// default constructor creates a Stack with capacity of 50
```

Important are comments that give new information such as:

```
topLook = -1;                          // initially no elements on the Stack
```

Because it's not obvious that `-1` means that the stack is empty.

You also should consider placing your comments before the line/method they concern, instead of after it. It makes the comments better readable and gives you more space to write longer comments if needed. Also for the methods you should consider using [`Javadoc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) style comments.

## Implementation

There are some problems with the functionality which maybe due to simplified instructions:

`top()` and `pop()` can't distinguish between an empty stack and a value of `-1`. Also returning having `push()` return an `int` (`1` or `-1`) isn't very nice.

There are better ways to do either of these things, but maybe the teacher hasn't introduced the necessary concepts yet. Maybe speak to the teacher about it.

Comment: Actually `topLook` is not the `currentElement` (an element is a value on the stack) but the index of the top element, so I would call it`topIndex` or `currentIndex`. Also, you can avoid the comment on `topLook = -1` by introducing a `private static final int EMPTY_INDEX = -1`.

Comment: Well it says current element in the comment for that line. Another argument against comments that repeat the line.

Answer (score 5):

### Broken functionality

I think that your code is broken: if you `push(-1)` and then `pop()` it, how do you know if the stack is empty or -1 is the actual value you got?

There is a problem here with returning 1/-1 to indicate if a push/pop is successful. 1/-1 and valid values for elements in the array. The usual approach for these cases is to throw exceptions. If the stack provides a `size()` method, and `MAX_SIZE` is public, the client can avoid these exceptions. If you still want to avoid exceptions, perhaps a boolean would be better than 1/-1.

### Other issues

Following [Java's naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), you should name your package with lower case, `stack`.

Also, as mentioned by [TwiN](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195315/166589), the names for `emptyCheck()` and `fullCheck()` can be improved. Method names should be verbs, and specifically, boolean methods should [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874378/9647022) that can be answered with yes/no.

Then, the comments are misplaced (they should be above, not to the right), and many of them are unneeded because they're so obvious. Comments like "default constructor creates a Stack with capacity of 50" are wrong; that's one of the reasons why you should avoid comments if possible, that is, if the code is clear enough.